# How to receive files over Bluetooth on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I am running **Ubuntu 20.04** with the classic *Gnome* desktop.  Apparently with this configuration ( or perhaps on any Ubuntu 20.04), you have to keep the *Bluetooth Settings* dialog open in order to receive files, otherwise Ubuntu will reject all transfers.  This is insane.  Is there a way around this?  I would like to send files from my phone to my laptop at any time without having to physically touch the laptop. And no, this won't be a security problem in my situation.

Comment: I think the Blueman bluetooth manager does that

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same issue, but: I have paired my phone previously, and I was able to send a file "successfully" from my phone, according to my phone, without having settings open. But no notifications in Ubuntu; nothing new in my Downloads folder (where it says it would be). However I did find the file at `~/.cache/obexd/4L931` !! I renamed it and moved it and it's fine. But it's quite unhelpful to fetch them from there! With settings open it goes into Downloads and I get notiification

Comment: yeah. this is Ubuntu now. a pain in the 4ss. i just wanted to send a file from my phone. but i figured out that the new rule is that you have to open up BT settings to go on. no matter that this will slow down the transfer because of the constant scanning but it's not even reliable/comfortable/smart idea that the user have to do several steps to get a file from a trusted/paired device. if there is a way to bring back the old behaviour let me know. devs lost their mind.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to send files from my phone to my laptop at any time without having to physically touch the laptop

If your devices are connected to the same Wifi network, you should definitively have a look to [GSConnect](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/).

You just have to install this Gnome extension and [the app "KDE Connect"](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.kde.kdeconnect_tp/) (the name is misleading, you don't need KDE) on your phone.

Then you can easily send files (even multiple at once) from your phone to your computer using the Share menu. No need for validation on the computer

I'm using it since monthes, works flawless

Comment: Is it faster than Bluetooth?  Bluetooth is pretty slow.

Comment: I did a test and had something like 100MB in 20s (500KB/s)